# Mixed effects model for nonlinear equation

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, mixed-models

I have an equation to fit:

y = a * x/(1 + (b * x)^c)

a = max y/x at low x i.e. initial slope

b = rate of decline in y as x increases

c determines shape of the curve

I would like to fit the equation above using a mixed effects model, with a random effect of group on the intercept, slope, and the c term. If the equation needs to be linearized that is okay. I keep getting the error "Error in nlformula(mc <- match.call()) :
is(nlform <- eval(form[[2]]), "formula") is not TRUE".

How can I do this in R?

Code for a nl mixed effects model:

```
shep <- function(x, a, b, c) {
  y_pred <- a * x / (1 + (b * x)^c)
  return(y_pred)
}

nform <- ~ a * x / (1 + (b * x)^c)
shepfun <- deriv(nform, namevec=c("a", "b", "c"),
              function.arg=c("x","a", "b", "c"))

initial= c(a=342.89, b=30.59, c=1)


fitme <- nlmer(y ~ shepfun(x, a, b, c) + (1 | Group), data = dat, start=initial)
```

Data below:

```
dput(dat[,c("Group","y","x")])
structure(list(Group= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L
), levels = c("Big CR", "Coal CR", "Elk CR", "Goat CR", "Granite CR", 
"Lion CR", "Lower Goat CR", "Middle Squeezer CR", "Morrison CR", 
"NF Coal CR", "Ole CR", "SF Coal CR", "Squeezer CR", "Upper Goat CR", 
"Upper Squeezer CR", "Whale CR", "Wounded Buck CR"), class = "factor"), 
    y = c(50.03436426, 29.6619718333333, 21.3333333333333, 
    17.5644444466667, 10.9090909066667, 1.33333333333333, 3.926589776, 
    9.74298464, 12.6666666666667, 25.6666666666667, 18.73469388, 
    16.11965812, 28.6349206333333, 58.4074074066667, 36.7659574466667, 
    30.1363636333333, 32.37777778, 10, 13.93939394, 32.6210045666667, 
    46.7801418466667, 44.12658228, 36.9047619066667, 37.5257731933333, 
    19.53488372, 23.8095238066667, 4.8, 1.10168078533333, 12.6, 
    50.08695652, 7.33333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 15.05376344, 
    29.7721519, 19.25, 25.2470588266667, 29.5909090933333, 21.09722222, 
    26.57777778, 10.98039216, 30.68992248, 22.2189054733333, 
    24.9263157866667, 16.4833333333333, 19.0188679266667, 37.5, 
    20.73429952, 39.79288026, 20.1165048533333, 30.3003663, 21.81818182, 
    21.3918128666667, 19.6756756733333, 20.6666666666667, 2.836471968, 
    13.0888888866667, 12.6666666666667, 8.15514054, 10, 4.41666666666667, 
    6.96, 8.5106383, 21.3333333333333, 32.4133333333333, 14.875, 
    10.7916666666667, 8.08080808, 10.2702702733333, 25.14285714, 
    7.56989247333333, 14.9787234066667, 15.44827586, 19.1020408133333, 
    7.55555555333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.98039216, 18.60465116, 
    16.1333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
    5.33333333333333, 24, 20.6666666666667, 30.4411764733333, 
    23.2962962933333, 63.05084746, 20.6666666666667, 58.5347985333333, 
    49.18996416, 35.4430379733333, 48.32982456, 57.1358024666667, 
    26.1333333333333, 59.9925925933333, 77.0833333333333, 65.3195876266667, 
    62.58064516, 52.5821596266667, 105, 32.3037974666667, 17.90804598, 
    25.31073446, 9.52, 24.92307692, 9.33333333333333, 20.3333333333333, 
    13, 11, 27.90277778, 15.3333333333333, 25.1700680266667, 
    14.31884058, 16.6666666666667, 16, 41.95767196, 24.5333333333333, 
    13.8461538466667, 13.0666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 11.3333333333333, 
    20.5050505066667, 18.75, 9.33333333333333, 14.71264368, 83.8666666666667, 
    50.9390681, 27.2333333333333, 50.30420712, 57.11442786, 75.8137254666667, 
    46.8841607533333, 64.5882352933333, 3.401360544, 62.84126984, 
    12.4, 57.92063492, 1.50617283933333, 57.7073170733333, 5.33333333333333, 
    20.5333333333333, 25.7627118666667, 23.4347826066667, 19.7727272733333, 
    16.1, 27.1515151533333, 45.6038647333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    0.666666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 6.588235294, 33.25170068, 
    32.3076923066667, 3.33333333333333, 4.24036956666667, 6, 
    5.30975916533333, 9.62962962666667, 4.66666666666667, 36.8609271533333, 
    25.3255813933333, 30.0487804866667, 4.925925926, 4.48697225266667, 
    2.66666666666667, 10, 8.04597701333333, 11.3333333333333, 
    10, 12, 2.78260869533333, 2.66666666666667, 8.28571428666667, 
    21.2105263133333, 31.1538461533333, 13.2173913066667, 7.43589743333333, 
    14.6666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 20.8333333333333, 25.1234567933333, 
    25.81560284, 15.3333333333333, 19.54285714, 10.7466666666667, 
    9.33333333333333, 8, 16, 19.9689922466667, 10, 15.12, 2.19047619066667, 
    12.0888888866667, 19.3333333333333, 2.823529412, 13.3333333333333, 
    9.16594128, 19.8333333333333, 22.6285714266667, 10.9090909066667, 
    16.2095238066667, 29.2307692333333, 15.5833333333333, 14.98245614, 
    40.18079096, 36.8547008533333, 31.9444444466667, 9.89333333333333, 
    4.336925954, 69.5338346, 13.87755102, 14.9333333333333, 26.08955224, 
    47.37078652, 22.8194444466667, 25.5163398666667, 3.43434343466667, 
    11.6097561, 15.5555555533333, 10.4347826066667, 18.12121212, 
    17.3333333333333, 16.7272727266667, 51.24919094, 19.1489361733333, 
    27.9545454533333, 9.82222222, 13.5714285733333, 9.62962962666667, 
    6.02898550733333), x = c(0.328497125650151, 0.342184505885574, 
    0.437996167533534, 0.218998083766767, 0.0273747604708459, 
    0.150561182589652, 0.191623323295921, 0.0821242814125376, 
    0.177935943060498, 0.410621407062688, 0.46537092800438, 0.437996167533534, 
    0.301122365179305, 0.164248562825075, 0.164248562825075, 
    0.150561182589652, 0.205310703531344, 0.506433068710649, 
    0.547495209416918, 0.287434984943882, 0.314809745414728, 
    0.109499041883384, 0.123186422118806, 0.0821242814125376, 
    0.109499041883384, 0.287434984943882, 0.0547495209416918, 
    0.218998083766767, 0.218998083766767, 0.0547495209416918, 
    0.191623323295921, 0.396934026827265, 3.3997441052824, 2.48583439956132, 
    3.56424785231219, 2.86967647596417, 3.3997441052824, 4.73405227563517, 
    3.01590202887955, 2.77828550539207, 3.07073661122281, 2.90623286419302, 
    3.25351855236703, 3.41802229939682, 3.19868397002376, 2.44927801133248, 
    2.12027051727289, 1.66331566441236, 1.55364649972583, 1.53536830561141, 
    1.37086455858161, 1.40742094681046, 0.73112776457686, 0.511789435203802, 
    0.639736794004752, 0.603180405775909, 0.44018643190057, 0.349559813568099, 
    0.401346452615225, 0.854479544277576, 0.414293112377007, 
    1.10046607975142, 0.919212843086484, 0.595546349041947, 1.17814603832211, 
    0.699119627136199, 1.03573278094252, 0.867426204039358, 0.841532884515795, 
    0.80269290523045, 0.97099948213361, 0.893319523562921, 0.932159502848265, 
    0.737959606421543, 0.168306576903159, 0.349559813568099, 
    0.245986535473848, 0.479026411185914, 0.168306576903159, 
    0.297773174520974, 0.323666494044537, 0.103573278094252, 
    0.257653834495302, 0.257653834495302, 0.121248863291907, 
    0.242497726583813, 0.409214913610185, 0.36374658987572, 0.621400424371022, 
    0.500151561079115, 0.682024856016975, 0.409214913610185, 
    0.560775992725068, 0.439527129433162, 0.575932100636557, 
    0.36374658987572, 0.469839345256138, 0.424371021521673, 0.212185510760837, 
    0.45468323734465, 0.670933113129645, 0.867052023121387, 1.75474814203138, 
    1.96118909991742, 1.45540875309661, 1.3934764657308, 1.36251032204789, 
    1.05284888521883, 0.949628406275805, 1.20767960363336, 0.774153592072667, 
    1.4037985136251, 1.4037985136251, 0.949628406275805, 1.03220478943022, 
    0.609000825763832, 0.815441783649876, 0.433526011560694, 
    0.990916597853014, 1.20767960363336, 0.712221304706854, 0.639966969446738, 
    0.660611065235343, 0.268373245251858, 0.309661436829067, 
    2.33064014916097, 2.67246737103791, 2.08203853325047, 3.07644499689248, 
    1.61591050341827, 1.52268489745183, 1.55376009944065, 1.95773772529521, 
    0.74580484773151, 1.39838408949658, 0.52827843380982, 0.435052827843381, 
    0.652579241765072, 0.870105655686762, 0.279676817899316, 
    1.2119328775637, 1.08763206960845, 0.932256059664388, 1.55376009944065, 
    1.24300807955252, 0.932256059664388, 0.683654443753884, 0.310752019888129, 
    0.341827221876942, 0.652579241765072, 1.33623368551896, 1.6780609073959, 
    1.61591050341827, 1.6780609073959, 1.95773772529521, 0.994406463642014, 
    1.24300807955252, 1.2119328775637, 0.652579241765072, 0.510783200908059, 
    0.638479001135074, 0.297956867196368, 0.312145289443814, 
    0.368898978433598, 0.482406356413167, 0.411464245175936, 
    0.297956867196368, 0.297956867196368, 0.227014755959137, 
    0.439841089670829, 0.411464245175936, 0.624290578887628, 
    0.482406356413167, 0.454029511918275, 0.92485549132948, 0.130057803468208, 
    0.968208092485549, 2.03757225433526, 0.852601156069364, 1.64739884393064, 
    1.76300578034682, 1.22832369942197, 1.35838150289017, 1.48843930635838, 
    1.63294797687861, 1.77745664739884, 0.852601156069364, 0.867052023121387, 
    0.520231213872832, 0.563583815028902, 0.794797687861272, 
    0.794797687861272, 0.679190751445087, 0.505780346820809, 
    0.260115606936416, 0.823699421965318, 0.346820809248555, 
    0.173410404624277, 0.534682080924855, 0.317919075144509, 
    1.11612443600095, 1.13195598828465, 0.941977360880234, 0.862819599461727, 
    0.0949893137022085, 0.253304836539223, 0.22164173197182, 
    0.277052164964775, 0.134568194411462, 0.316631045674028, 
    0.387873030950685, 0.569935882213251, 0.609514762922505, 
    0.5620201060714, 0.269136388822924, 0.324546821815879, 0.308715269532178, 
    0.44328346394364, 0.213725955829969, 0.284967941106626, 0.34037837409958, 
    0.245389060397372, 0.229557508113671, 0.269136388822924, 
    0.245389060397372, 0.213725955829969, 0.229557508113671, 
    0.284967941106626, 0.205810179688118, 0.253304836539223)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 96L, 97L, 101L, 102L, 104L, 105L, 108L, 
109L, 110L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 128L, 129L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 142L, 143L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 164L, 165L, 167L, 169L, 195L, 
196L, 197L, 198L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 213L, 214L, 221L, 222L, 228L, 230L, 231L, 
232L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 
245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 254L, 263L, 265L, 
266L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 
278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 289L, 
290L, 293L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 352L, 
353L, 355L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 
374L, 375L, 376L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 445L, 446L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 
451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 
462L, 463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 468L, 469L, 481L, 485L, 487L, 488L, 
490L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 
502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 510L, 511L, 513L, 514L, 
515L, 516L, 517L, 519L))
```

Comment: First work on fitting the model, then work on plotting results - don't try to combine these separate questions into one.

Comment: There are quite a few resources for fitting non-linear mixed effects models. What have you tried and where did you get stuck? If you don't demonstrate attempts/effort, then your question sounds like you want someone to just write code for you.

Comment: @GregorThomas I updated with the code I have tried and the error I receive

Comment: This won't work with `lmer`: you have to use `nlme()` or `lme4::nlmer()` (I'd recommend the former ...) (As far as I know there's no way to linearize this equation - the Michaelis-Menten (i.e. your equation with `c=1`) can be linearized by using a 1/x transformation, but the power screws things up.)

Comment: That's not how `nlmer` formulas work ...  see `?nlmer` ...

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be challenging, since I have trouble fitting a single Shepherd function to the (very noisy) data even before I start trying a mixed model.  (It's conceivable but unlikely that adding random effects would make the problem *easier*, if the among-group variability is messing everything up, but I doubt it.)

Dumping code here for now, will come back and clean up/explain more later.

### preliminary Michaelis-Menten/Beverton-Holt (c=1) fits

```r
g1 <- glm(y ~ I(1/x), data = dat, family = gaussian(link ="inverse"))
## 1/y = b0 + b1/x
## -> y = 1/(b0+b1/x) = (1/b1)*x/(1 + (b0/b1)*x)
cc0 <- unname(coef(g1))
cc1 <- c(a = 1/cc0[2], b = cc0[1]/cc0[2])

plot(y~x, data = dat)
with(as.list(cc1), curve((a*x)/(1+b*x), add = TRUE, col = 2))

## param:  Vm*x/(K + x) -> a = Vm/K, b = 1/K
n1 <- nls(y ~ SSmicmen(x, Vm, K), data = dat)
cc2 <- with(as.list(coef(n1)), c(a = Vm/K, b = 1/K))
all.equal(cc1, cc2, tolerance = 1e-4)
```

### Shepherd fit (homogeneous)

```r
shep <- deriv(~a * x/(1 + (b * x)^c),
              namevec = c("a", "b", "c"),
              function.arg = c("x", "a", "b", "c"))
n2 <- nls(y ~ shep(x, a, b, c),
          data = dat,
          ## starting values taken from B-H fit
          start = c(a = 2000, b = 91, c = 1),
          control = nls.control(minFactor = 1e-9, maxiter = 1000,
                                warnOnly = TRUE))
```

### mixed model

This isn't working, but I think it's the correct syntax:

```r
library(nlme)
nlme(y ~ shep(x, a, b, c),
     random = a ~ 1 | Group,
     fixed = a + b + c ~ 1,
     data = dat,
     start = c(a = 2000, b = 91, c = 1))
```

Comment: thank you. I've updated what I worked through after your initial comment in the main part of my question. We may be running into the same error, I am not sure, but that was using lme4:nlmer. I'll try the last chunk you put. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: I tried but the data is just too noisy. I replace `b` with `exp(b)` to ensure that the parameter is positive. Using `nlsList`, I was then able to get successful fits for the first five groups only. I tried single `nls` fits for some of the other groups but no success. I then tried `nlme` with the data subset to the first five groups but again had no success. Maybe a Bayesian non-linear mixed-effects model could be a last resort but I'm only familar with package rstanarm and unfortunately its `stan_nlmer` function requires a self-starting model.